# Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'call'. Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot' Tried calling: call()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: call()

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      _HomekitchenListState.build.. (package:pigeon/cook_pages/homekitchen_listpage.dart:26:62)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:449:22)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1130:28)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild. (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1143:55)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomekitchenList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomekitchenListState createState() => _HomekitchenListState();
}

class _HomekitchenListState extends State<HomekitchenList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream:
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Homekitchens").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            print("snapshot from homecooks doesnt have any data");
            return Text(
                "snapshot from homecooks doesnt have any data"); //replace with popup in future
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot homekitchens = snapshot.data().docs[index];
                print(homekitchens);
                //var homekitchens= kitchencollection.data()[index];
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13, vertical: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                          // ignore: missing_return, missing_return, missing_return, missing_return
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "${homekitchens.id}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Comfortaa",
                            // ignore: missing_return
                            fontSize: 30),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a smaller piece of code that fails similarly, or point out what you've tried for debugging.  Can you mark the lines that are being described in the stack trace?

Comment: `DocumentSnapshot homekitchens = snapshot.data().docs[index];` - here `data()` should be changed to `data`.

Comment: @MuthuThavamani thank you so much it worked,hope you don't mind i added an answer myself

Comment: Cool; keep going!

Answer (score 0):

`DocumentSnapshot homekitchens = snapshot.data().docs[index];` - here `data()` should be changed to `data`
credit- Muthu Thavamani